# set @ActiveProfiles from test runner class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

sorry for my bad english. I need to use different active profiles for testing. Can I specify them in the launching class?
Launch class:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/features",
        tags = "@extraPaymentWithCash",
        glue = "ru.zoo.penguin.cucumber.steps",
        snippets = SnippetType.CAMELCASE
)
//@ActiveProfiles({"h2", "h2_tm", "cash"}) This doesn't work, but i need to use these profiles 
public class ExtraPaymentWithCashCucumberFeaturesTest {
}
```

Step class:

```
@ActiveProfiles({"h2", "h2_tm"}) //i need to get rid of it 
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {OperationTerminalManagerConfig.class, MainConfig.class, OperationTerminalHandlerConfig.class, PaymentTerminalHandlerConfig.class, BankConfig.class,
        ManagersConfig.class, DaoConfig.class, DatabaseConfig.class, PechkinsConfig.class, ShooterConfig.class, ProcessManagerConfig.class,
        CancelCucumberTestConfiguration.class, PaymentTerminalManagerConfig.class, CancelTerminalManagerConfig.class, CancelTerminalHandlerConfig.class})
@Transactional
@Log4j2
public class CancelCucumberBaseTest {
    @Autowired
    protected SmsMessageManager smsMessageManager;
    ....
}
```

Comment: Can you please use a translator from native language to English?